# Access denied error, when trying to build code on a perforce workspace using Ant.

Tags: java, ant, perforce, access-denied

I have started working on Perforce recently. I have a source code, which I build using Ant build.I have correctly checked-in all the files of the source code in the perforce server (which is a local server on my machine).

Now, when I create a new user in perforce, get latest revision of the checked-in code from perforce depot to my workspace, and try to build using Ant, I get an access denied error. The same source code that I keep in a backup folder and build using Ant, it builds correctly. I dont know why am I getting this access denied error.

Comment: Details! What's the *exact* Perforce command you run; what's the *exact* error message you receive? Cut and paste directly from your build script and output, using `ant -verbose` if necessary to get more insight into what's going on.

Comment: Perforce Command - p4 sync. (to get latest revision of files - this works)
Error (when Ant build is run on the synced files in any user workspace) - Java FileNotFound Exception - Access is denied. 
However, I figured this issue is because there are certain files, which when synced from server, are not the same as they are in the backup folder.
Certain files, which when checked in to the depot- and then synced back to a workspace - change.

Comment: How are the synced files changing? Could it be RCS keyword expansion? Also, check the line ending setting in the client. Is there anything in your Ant build that is making assumptions about where things are?

Answer (score 0):

create a new user in perforce ? This may be the reason as new user might not have read/write access to your work space

Comment: I checked all permission constraints. Issue is not permissions related. Things is - there are certain files, which when checked into the depot- and then synced back to a workspace - change.
This I found when I compared the workspace code to the backup code.
Dont know why is this happening. Is there something wrong with the way I have configured  the server?